# Laravel website feeded by api

Tags: laravel, api

In normal laravel controller I return a view with the data

`return view('folder.page', compact('data'))`

But I'm building my website with an API to work also in mobile devices, how should I build my html with the API?

- Create a controller that calls the api and return the view with the data
- Build with javascript functions that calls the api and build the html
- Another way

**Update**
Important thing, the API is in the same project, it isn't an external api

Comment: If you will get data from some external API then why you are using Laravel?

Comment: @MarcinMagdziarz updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `ViewComposer`, in this way you can use the variables in your website. 
You can find more about `ViewComposers` at the following link:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers

You can then use the `ViewComposer` to do a request to your API and use that data. The data will then be assigned to your blade as a normal variable (such as `{{$foo}}`)

Comment: As long as your API is accessible from your application, yes. If it's closed off and no other application can reach it, no.